# rxjava - how to handle exception within map()

Tags: dictionary, reactive-programming, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I am new to RxJava and still exploring its wonders.

I am transforming the `Response` object into a `LoginSession` object using `map()` operator but there can be an `IOException` thrown during transformation. Following is the example code.

## Observable

```
public Observable<LoginSession> login(@NonNull String username, @NonNull String password) {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Response> subscriber) {
                loginInternal(username, password, subscriber);
            }
        }).map(response -> {
            try {
                LoginSession session = Utils.methodThatCanReturnAnIoException(response.body().byteStream(), LoginSession.class);
                return session;
            } catch(IOException e){
                return null; // what should I do here ????
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

## Subscriber

```
login("username", "password").subscribe( loginSession -> {
    //i hate checking for null here. there should be a better way...
    if(loginSession != null){
        Log.d("MY_SESSION", "Login session successful.");
    } else {
        Log.d("MY_SESSION", "Login Session is null unfortunately.");
    }
});
```

What is the best way to handle this scenario? except checking for null in `subscribe()` which I am sure not the best way of doing it.

Comment: Filter out null values.

Comment: As for the other one, change map into flatmap, make your operation inside an Observable.create() or Observable.defer() and handle the errors there.

Comment: but i want the subscriber to know that an error has occurred. with filter() subscriber will never know that transformation failed.

Comment: I did thought about flatMap too. will try that .

Comment: Then let it fail and add a retry policy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern you are after is to use `flatMap`:

```
public Observable<LoginSession> login(@NonNull String username, @NonNull String password) {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Response> subscriber) {
                loginInternal(username, password, subscriber);
            }
        }).flatMap(response -> {
            try {
                LoginSession session = Utils.methodThatCanReturnAnIoException(response.body().byteStream(), LoginSession.class);
                return Observable.just(session);
            } catch(IOException e){
                return Observable.error(e);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

Then use the `onError` method in the subscriber.

Comment: yes I tried flatMap and that works fine for this situation :). accepting this answer.